# Attempting to pass options using Selenium in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've tried to pass a couple of options (ones to disable images from loading, extensions, basically anything to make the script faster) however when I do

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
```

I get an error saying webdriver.Chrome needs to be a path. Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

The chrome driver path is to be specified.

> browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=option)

If the problem still continues, please do share the complete function.